# XSD Validation Stack overflow Exception

Tags: java, xml, xsd, stack-overflow

Can anyone explain what is the use of [this](http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema-full-checking) option while validating XSD? If I set `true` or `false` what are the background things happening? Which case needs to set this option to `true` and which case needs to set this to `false`? If my XSD so more than `10MB` I'm getting a `StackOverflow` exception when I set this option to `true`.

**Code Example:**

```
SymbolTable sym = new SymbolTable(BIG_PRIME);
preparser.setProperty(GRAMMAR_POOL, grammarPool);
preparser.setFeature(NAMESPACES_FEATURE_ID, true);
preparser.setFeature(VALIDATION_FEATURE_ID, true);
preparser.setFeature(SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FEATURE_ID, true);
preparser.setFeature(SCHEMA_FULL_CHECKING_FEATURE_ID, true);
MyXMLErrorHandler myXMLErrorHandler = new MyXMLErrorHandler(errorOutput);
XMLGrammarPreparser preparser = new XMLGrammarPreparser(sym);
Grammar g = preparser.preparseGrammar(XMLGrammarDescription.XML_SCHEMA, stringToXIS((String) inputOptions.schemas.get(i)));
```

Comment: If you know your schema is valid then you don't need to check it thoroughly every time you use it, and you can save time by suppressing some of the checks. But if running with all the checks enabled blows available resources, then you don't know whether the schema is valid or not, so switching off the verification isn't safe.

Comment: @MichaelKay - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/features.html:

> Enable full schema constraint checking, including checking which may be time-consuming or memory intensive. Currently, particle unique attribution constraint checking and particle derivation resriction checking are controlled by this option.

You will need to understand the meaning of 'unique particle attribution' and 'particle derivation restriction'. Google should be able to help you with that.